# In RealityView ,how can i make a portal with a custom model that i imorpt with composer pro?

Tags: swiftui

```
func makePortal(world: Entity) async -> Entity {
        let portal = Entity()
        
        //mesh
        portal.components[ModelComponent.self] = .init(mesh:.generatePlane(width: 0.5, height: 0.5, cornerRadius: 0.25),
                                                       materials: [PortalMaterial()])
        portal.components[PortalComponent.self] = .init(target: world)
        
        return portal
    }
```

i want to change the mesh:.generatePlane with custom mesh. or make a "PortalMaterial" in shader editor..
or can replace the entity material with Portal Material